# Timestamp Google Drive's "last modified"

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-timestamp

I'm trying to get a cell in my Google sheet to reference the last modified timestamp from the Google Drive of the same file (not folder).

In other words, I'd like for a cell to update its timestamp for an entire Google sheet, whenever a change is made.  It should reference every sheet within the file itself.

Comment: That makes sense.  Is there a way for this to happen any other way?  I just want the cell to tell me when the last time the spreadsheet has been modified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

IMHO the easiest way is to add  `=NOW()` as a cell formula.

## Explanation

The Google Sheets spreadsheet recalculation settings default value is "On change", that means that the result of NOW will be updated everytime a change is made on your spreadsheet.

[image: Calculation settings]

## References

- [Set a spreadsheet’s location and calculation settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?hl=en)
- [NOW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981?hl=en)